# How to extract one row from XML using R?

Tags: html, xml, r, extract

I read a data from a link like these.

```
> library(XML)
> url <- "http://biostat.jhsph.edu/~jleek/contact.html"
> html <- htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes=T)
```

then I want to extract tenth row from that to count its number of character. what should I do?

Comment: What does "one row" of XML mean? How do you want to extract it? It would be helpful if you could provide a reproducible example with sample input and desired output.

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid URL

Comment: I add a URL, I want to extract tenth line from that.

Comment: You mean you want to get `<link rel="stylesheet" href="images/PixelGreen.css" type="text/css">` out of the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?  Find the tenth line down from the start of html (id = main), extract its Value, and count the characters in that extracted content.

```
> url <- "http://biostat.jhsph.edu/~jleek/contact.html"
> html <- htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes=T)
> xpathSApply(html, "//div[@id = 'main']", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
[1] "Contact Information\n\n\t\t\t  Address \n\t\t\t  \n\t\t\t  Johns Hopkins University \n\t\t\t  Bloomberg School of Public Health \n\t\t\t  615 North Wolfe Street \n\t\t\t  Baltimore, MD 21205-2179 \n\t\t\t  Phone\n\t\t\t  410-955-1166 (I am much easier to reach by email)\n\t\t\t  Fax\n\t\t\t  410-955-0958\n\t\t\t  Email\n\t\t\t   jleek || jhsph dot edu \n\t\t\t  Twitter\n\t\t\t   @leekgroup\n\t\t\t  Blog\n\t\t\t   Simply Statistics"
```

Then wrap the above with `nchar()`and assign it to an object, here character.

```
> characters <- nchar(xpathSApply(html, "//div[@id = 'main']", xmlValue, trim = TRUE))
> characters
[1] 369
```

You can remove the tab and new line markers, perhaps with `gsub()`.